# Filling an Dictionary with a plist

Tags: ios, dictionary, plist

I have this .plist file stored in my Documents directory, and now I want to read it into a Dictionary.
Somehow, while the .plist is on the right location, and seems to be structured correctly, my Dictionary remains NIL after trying this:

```
-(void) initPicker {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *plistPath =[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"schools.plist"];
    NSLog(plistPath);
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
    self.Schools=dictionary;


    NSArray *component = [self.Schools allKeys];
    NSArray *sorted =[component sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
    self.Names=sorted;
    NSString *selectedName = [self.Names objectAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *array = [Schools objectForKey:selectedName];
    self.Urls = array; 
}
```

Can any of you see what I'm doing wrong? Or help my to find a way to trouble shoot this?
Thanks ahead

Comment: Is the .plist really a dictionary at top level? What is the code to save the .plist?

Comment: That might be the problem: the plist opens with

<plist version="1.0">
<array>
 <dict>
  <key>ID</key>
  <string>ffefe0f7-23bf-471f-8e99-58ada0229921</string>
  <key>Name</key>
  <string>2College</string>

Comment: Seems cleary to be a NSArray at top level rather than a NSDictionary.

Comment: Yup, fixing that. If you post this as an answer, I can reward you